# How to build features using pandas column and a dictionary efficiently?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, machine-learning, feature-extraction

I have a machine learning problem where I am calculating bigram Jaccard similarity of a pandas dataframe text column with values of a dictionary. Currently I am storing them as a list and then converting them to columns. This is proving to be very slow in production. Is there a more efficient way to do it?

Following are the steps I am currently following:
For each key in dict:
1. Get bigrams for the pandas column and the dict[key]
2. Calculate Jaccard similarity
3. Append to an empty list
4. Store the list in the dataframe
5. Convert the list to columns

```py
from itertools import tee, islice

def count_ngrams(lst, n):
    tlst = lst
    while True:
        a, b = tee(tlst)
        l = tuple(islice(a, n))
        if len(l) == n:
            yield l
            next(b)
            tlst = b
        else:
            break

def n_gram_jaccard_similarity(str1, str2,n):

    a = set(count_ngrams(str1.split(),n))
    b = set(count_ngrams(str2.split(),n))

    intersection = a.intersection(b)
    union = a.union(b)

    try:
        return len(intersection) / float(len(union))

    except:
        return np.nan

def jc_list(sample_dict,row,n):
    sim_list = []
    for key in sample_dict:
       sim_list.append(n_gram_jaccard_similarity(sample_dict[key],row["text"],n))

    return str(sim_list)
```

Using the above functions to build the bigram Jaccard similarity features as follows:

```py
df["bigram_jaccard_similarity"]=df.apply(lambda row: jc_list(sample_dict,row,2),axis=1)
df["bigram_jaccard_similarity"] = df["bigram_jaccard_similarity"].map(lambda x:[float(i) for i in [a for a in [s.replace(',','').replace(']', '').replace('[','') for s in x.split()] if a!='']])
df[[i for i in sample_dict]] = pd.DataFrame(df["bigram_jaccard_similarity"].values.tolist(), index= df.index)
```

Sample input:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=["id","text"],index=None)
df.loc[0] = ["1","this is a sample text"]

import collections

sample_dict = collections.defaultdict()
sample_dict["r1"] = "this is sample 1" 
sample_dict["r2"] = "is sample" 
sample_dict["r3"] = "sample text 2"
```

Expected output:

[image]

Comment: could you share some data and desired output? It feels, like you could essentially use scikit-learns [jaccard-similarity](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.jaccard_score.html#sklearn.metrics.jaccard_score) and not really using pandas. Besides applying per row is slow :) Vectorize!

Comment: @Quickbeam2k1 : I have added the sample input and output. Can you please provide an example of Vectorizing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, this is more difficult than I though, due to some broadcasting issues of sparse matrices. Additionally, in the short period of time I was not able to fully vectorize it.

I added an additional text row to the frame:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=["id","text"],index=None)
df.loc[0] = ["1","this is a sample text"]
df.loc[1] = ["2","this is a second sample text"]

import collections

sample_dict = collections.defaultdict()
sample_dict["r1"] = "this is sample 1" 
sample_dict["r2"] = "is sample" 
sample_dict["r3"] = "sample text 2"
```

We will use the following modules/functions/classes:

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
from scipy.sparse import csr_matrix
import numpy as np
```

and define a CountVectorizer to create character based n_grams

```
ngram_vectorizer = CountVectorizer(ngram_range=(2, 2), analyzer="char")
```

feel free to choose the n-grams you need. I'd advise to take an existing tokenizer and n-gram creator. You should find plenty of those. Also the CountVectorizer can be tweaked extensively (e.g. convert to lowercase, get rid of whitespace etc.)

We concatenate all the data:

```
all_data = np.concatenate((df.text.to_numpy(),np.array(list(sample_dict.values()))))
```

we do this, as our vectorizer needs to have a common indexing scheme for all the tokens appearing.

Now let's fit the Count vectorizer and transform the data accordingly:

```
ngrammed = ngram_vectorizer.fit_transform(all_data) >0
```

`ngrammed` is now a sparse matrix containing the identifiers to the tokens appearing in the respective rows and not the counts anymore as before. you can inspect the [`ngram_vecotrizer`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.CountVectorizer.html)  and find a mapping from tokens to column ids.

Next we want to compare every grammes entry from the sample dict against every row of our ngrammed text data. We need some magic here:

```
texts = ngrammed[:len(df)]
samples = ngrammed[len(df):]
text_rows = len(df)

jaccard_similarities = []
for key, ngram_sample in zip(sample_dict.keys(), samples):
    repeated_row_matrix = (csr_matrix(np.ones([text_rows,1])) * ngram_sample).astype(bool)
    support = texts.maximum(repeated_row_matrix)
    intersection = texts.multiply(repeated_row_matrix).todense()
    jaccard_similarities.append(pd.Series((intersection.sum(axis=1)/support.sum(axis=1)).A1, name=key))
```

`support` is the boolean array, that measures the union of the n-grams over both comparable. `intersection` is only True if a token is present in both comparable. Note that `.A1` represents a `matrix`-object as the underlying base array.

Now

```
pd.concat(jaccard_similarities, axis=1)
```

gives

```
         r1        r2        r3
0  0.631579  0.444444  0.500000
1  0.480000  0.333333  0.384615
```

you can concat is as well to `df` and obtain with

```
pd.concat([df, pd.concat(jaccard_similarities, axis=1)], axis=1)
  id                          text        r1        r2        r3
0  1         this is a sample text  0.631579  0.444444  0.500000
1  2  this is a second sample text  0.480000  0.333333  0.384615
```

Comment: Thanks @Quickbeam2k1! Couple of quick clarifications: 1. Firstly, ```jaccard_score(texts.T, repeated_row_matrix.T, average=None)``` throws up an error when I use it for dataframe with just one row. 2. Giving ngram_range =(2,2) doesn't yield the same result as my expected output. How do we fix these?

Comment: Okay, I think I fixed two issues. Firstly, I realized that you want to create character based `n_grams`. Btw, I think your implementation of `n_grams` is false. Verify this in the case `n=1`. If not. Why do you call it n_grams. Moreover, there was an issue with count multiplicity, which I deleted now (this is the `>0`) you'll find above. Hope this helps

Comment: I was able to fix the n_gram computation but ```jaccard_score(texts.T, repeated_row_matrix.T, average=None)``` still throws up the error ```TypeError: len() of unsized object``` while using it for dataframe with just one row.

Comment: Is it running with more than one row of text? Something strange is going on here (and I'm trying to find out where the bug is)

Comment: It is running with more than one row. In fact even with an empty row it works fine. I couldn't test out the .dense thing that you suggested.

Comment: Okay, finally, this should be an appropriate solution that correctly calculates jaccard similarity. Moreover, we got rid of `jaccard_score`

Comment: Thanks a lot for your effort Quickbeam2k1! That worked finally, need to check out the latency improvement now :)